# How to bind the value from the javascript to a view in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-echo

I have an `input field` in the blade.

```
<div id="id1">
<input id ="text1"  data-readOnly="true" data-max=300 value= 34/>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
 channel.bind('App\\Events\\ValueChange', function(data){
      target = data.id;
      value = data.value;
});
```

I need to bind the `value = data.value;` from the event to the attribute `value` in the Input field in the blade file.

How could I do this?
Could someone please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're doing there. Could you add some more details to your question?

Comment: What’s the problem? If you’re listening to broadcast events using Echo then you can receive the new value in the payload and update your `input` like you’ve demonstrated.

Comment: I want to know, how to bind the values triggered from the event to the input field `value attribute`, For ex, I used static value `34`, but the value should be returned from the Event. How to bind the value?

Comment: As has already been answered, get the element, and alter it's value with [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: @JustCarty, In the blade fiel, do I need to use the below to bind the value `<input value = "{{ value }}"/> ?

Comment: I think you're confusing JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by

```js
channel.bind('App\\Events\\ValueChange', function(data) {
    target = data.id;
    value = data.value;

    document.getElementById('text1').value = value;
});
```

Comment: how to bind that value from the script to the view in the input field?

Comment: @KovidaK I'm not sure how this _doesn't_ answer the question. When you say "bind" I imagine you want the value to update. That _will_ happen when your event updates.

Comment: @Mua Rachmaan, after adding `document.getElementById('text1').value = value;`, I could not see any changes in the value atrribute in the input field.

Comment: @JustCarty, If` <input  value = 20>` and when I trigger the value through event `document.getElementById('text1').value = value;` , then 20 should be replaced by the value triggered by the Event, Correct? . If I pass `event(eventname(45))` in the tinker.  `20` should be replaced by `45` in the browser.  But still Its `20`.

Comment: @KovidaK then you should probably ask another question, I think your call back is not being called. This has to do with wither pusher or laravel echo.